# json_encode pass php array to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I have a more dimensional php array that i want to pass to a javascript array.

This is the array:

> ```
> $this->_db_list_arrray[$this->getID()][$key] = $row;
> ```

its like "16":[[{"article_no_internal":"9987213"}]] and so on.
I encode it like this:

> ```
> $shipping_part_list_array = json_encode($db_obj->getArticleList($elements));
> ```

and in javascript

> ```
> alert("<?php  echo $shipping_part_list_array; ?>");
> ```

but the alert only shows [].

Is there a better way to pass php array to java script array?

```
array(1) {
  [16]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["article_no_internal"]=>
        string(6) "999184"
        ["article_name_internal"]=>
        string(29) "Geschenkbox Kerzenschein 2011"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["article_no_internal"]=>
        string(6) "999184"
        ["article_name_internal"]=>
        string(29) "Geschenkbox Kerzenschein 2011"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is in my console, now i need to parse to get the right data. Thank you

Comment: alert("<?php  echo $shipping_part_list_array; ?>");

Change to alert("<?php  echo addslashes ($shipping_part_list_array); ?>"); or see on raw html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put double quotes around the JSON encoded value; just the following will do:

```
alert(<?php echo $shipping_part_list_array; ?>);
```

Though, for debugging purposes the following would be better:

```
console.log(<?php echo $shipping_part_list_array; ?>);
```

Lastly, to assign it to a JavaScript variable:

```
var list = <?php echo $shipping_part_list_array; ?>;
```

Comment: `function Array() {
    [native code]
}`   i get this when i alert without "".

Comment: @Toma right, that's what I warned about in my answer, if you want to debug the object itself, you should use `console.log()`

Comment: with `console.log()` and simple quotes i get Array. In my error_log i gave out the `$db_obj->getArticleList($elements)`  the array is filled with data.

Comment: @Toma I've updated my answer, please check. Btw, I never said to put single quotes around the value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add single quotes to alert your JSON string:

```
alert('<?php  echo $shipping_part_list_array; ?>');
```